# AutoMapper not mapping object within object

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, asp.net-core-mvc

AutoMapper is currently not pulling down the `IpAddress` object within my `Server` object.  The end goal is go have my input already populated with the current IP Address in my edit view.  However, when I place a break point in my Controller, the `IpAddress` property is null so I can't get the actual address out of it.  I know I am doing something incorrectly with AutoMapper, but haven't been able to find a specific tutorial yet.  Thanks in advance!

[Break point screenie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtFxw.png)

ServersController.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var server = Mapper.Map<ServerViewModel>(await _context.Servers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id));
    if (server == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(server);
}
```

ServerViewModel.cs

```
public class ServerViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public OperatingSystem OS { get; set; }
    public MachineType MachineType { get; set; }
    public string AdminUserName { get; set; }
    public string AdminPassword { get; set; }
    public string EsxHost { get; set; }
    public int IpAddressId { get; set; }
    public IpAddress IpAddress { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> GetOperatingSystems()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> operatingSystems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(OperatingSystem));
        operatingSystems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Select",
            Value = ""
        });

        foreach(OperatingSystem val in values)
        {
            operatingSystems.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = val.ToString(),
                Value = val.ToString()
            });
        }
        return operatingSystems;
    }

    public List<SelectListItem> GetMachineTypes()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> machineTypes = new List<SelectListItem>();
        Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MachineType));
        machineTypes.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Select",
            Value = ""
        });

        foreach (MachineType val in values)
        {
            machineTypes.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = val.ToString(),
                Value = val.ToString()
            });
        }
        return machineTypes;
    }
}
```

Server.cs

```
public class Server
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public OperatingSystem OS { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Machine Type")]
    public MachineType MachineType { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Admin User Name")]
    public string AdminUserName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Admin Password")]
    public string AdminPassword { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "ESX Host")]
    public string EsxHost { get; set; }
    public int IpAddressId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IpAddressId")]
    public IpAddress IpAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
    Mapper.Initialize(config =>
    {
        config.CreateMap<IpAddressViewModel, IpAddress>().ReverseMap();
        config.CreateMap<ServerViewModel, Server>().ReverseMap();
    });
```

EDIT:  After some reading, I have discovered that I can add a `.Include()` clause to my query to bring in the `IpAddress` object.  My new `ServersController.cs` code is below.  However, I am still a little confused.  Isn't this the type of thing that Automapper was meant to take care of automatically?  Am I missing the entire point of Automapper?

NEW ServersController.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var server = Mapper.Map<ServerViewModel>(await _context.Servers.Include(s => s.IpAddress).SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id));

    if (server == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(server);
}
```

Comment: Did you check if `_context.Servers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id).IpAddress` is null?

Comment: Please show you mapping and check that IpAddress is not null on your Server.

Comment: @C Sharper it is indeed null.  This makes me think I am doing something else wrong.  I was under the impression that Entity Framework would pull in the `IpAddress` object based on the `IpAddressId`.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @Rabban I added the mapper config section from my Startup.cs.  IpAddressId is not null on my server.  It is a foreign key linking back to the IpAddress table.

Comment: For lazy loading of `IpAddress` to work, mark this property as `virtual` in the EF Model.

Comment: I tend to avoid lazy loading in EF. for EF6 in the `System.Data.Entiy` ns there is an `Include` method you can use to bring in nav properties. `.Include(x => x.IpAddress)`

Comment: @CSharper check out the update above, please

Comment: Automapper can't map what isn't there. Also, you should give this a look https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions

Comment: @CSharper can you give an answer so I can give you credit for helping me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to go ahead and answer this to put some closure on it.

The key was adding a `.Include()` clause to my LINQ query to pull in objects attached to the parent object.

The correct way to do this is in my EDIT section above.  Further examples can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx).